# Scroll на JavaScript не работает

Tags: javascript, frontend, прокрутка

Пытаюсь сделать скрол - стрелочка которая перематывает на верх и затем меяется на стрелку вниз которая перематывает на старое положение.
Вот код JS:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
            var scrolled = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            if (scrolled >= document.documentElement.clientHeight){
                up.classList.remove("dnone");
                down.classList.add("dnone");

            }
        }
        function windowScroll(){
            var event = window.event.target;
             if (event.id == 'up'){
                 up.classList.add("dnone");
                 down.classList.remove("dnone");
                 var oldScroled = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                 alert (oldScroled); // число
                 window.scrollTo(0,0);
             } else  if (event.id == 'down'){
            alert (oldScroled); // underfined
            window.scrollTo(oldScroled);

         }
        }
```

Не работает скрол вниз. Попробывала просто вывети положение - при нажатие на кнопку вверх оно выводит число, а при нажатии кнопки вниз - `underfined`, как будто бы не видит переменную.

Comment: html и css добавьте

Comment: У вас `oldScroled` объявлена внутри  `windowScroll`, поэтому ее значение не сохраняется между вызовами этой функции. Вам нужно вынести это объявление из функции.

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно сказал @hindmost, это происходит из-за того, что вы объявляете `oldScroled` в одной области видимости `f (event.id == 'up'){...}`, а потом пытаетесь к нему обратиться в другой `else if (event.id == 'down'){...}`.

Следовательно, вам нужно объявить `oldScroled` где-нибудь выше и вне функции `windowScroll`. Например так:

```js
var oldScroled;

window.onscroll = function() {
    var scrolled = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (scrolled >= document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
        up.classList.remove("dnone");
        down.classList.add("dnone");

    }
}

function windowScroll() {
    var event = window.event.target;
    if (event.id == 'up') {
        up.classList.add("dnone");
        down.classList.remove("dnone");
        oldScroled = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    } else if (event.id == 'down') {
        window.scrollTo(oldScroled);
    }
}
```